# Spring boot only matches "/" when using custom filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot service that behaves not as expected. I wrote a custom auth filter and if I include it in my security config, it breaks the URI.

Its a very basic filter that doesn't do much, except reading the basic token and compares it to the stored token (restProperties)

```
public class BasicFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BasicFilter.class);
    private static String BASIC_PREFIX = "Basic ";
    private final RestProperties restProperties;
    private final String API_USER = "api_user";

    public BasicFilter(RequestMatcher requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, RestProperties restProperties) {
        super(requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher, authenticationManager);
        this.restProperties = restProperties;
    }

    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authorization == null) {
            log.warn("basic token not present");
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("");
        } else if (!authorization.startsWith(BASIC_PREFIX)) {
            log.error("Basic token malformed" + authorization);
            throw new BadCredentialsException("");
        } else if (!this.restProperties.getAuthorization().equals(authorization)) {
            log.error("basic token does not equal the properties basic token");
            throw new BadCredentialsException("");
        } else {
            log.info("user authenticated via basic authentication");
            return new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken("api_user", (Object)null, Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(Role.API_INTERN.getRole())));
        }
    }
}
```

My security config looks like that:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RestProperties restProperties;

    @Override
    protected void configure( final HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
        final BasicFilter basicFilter = new BasicFilter(
                RouteMatchHelper.combination( RouteMatchHelper.orRoutes( "/api/**" ), RouteMatchHelper.orRoutes( "/actuator/health" ) ),
                authenticationManager(), restProperties );
        // @formatter:off
        http.csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher( "/**" )
                .addFilterBefore( basicFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class )
                .addFilterBefore( new StatelessCSRFFilter(), BasicFilter.class )
                .securityContext()
                .securityContextRepository( new NullSecurityContextRepository() ).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy( SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS ).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/actuator/health" ).access("permitAll")
                .antMatchers( "/api/**" ).access("permitAll")
                .antMatchers( "/**" ).access( "denyAll" ).and().cors();
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

Now when I call the route `/api/user/login` it will fail with a 404. But the controller exists.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping( "/api/user/login" )
@RequiredArgsConstructor( onConstructor = @__( @Autowired ) )
public class AuthController {

    private final AuthService authService;

    @GetMapping
    public User authenticate( @RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password ) {
        return authService.authenticate( username, password );
    }

}
```

I'm also using an AccessLoggingInterceptor. The interceptor reads the HttpServletRequest URI and logs it. It only logs `/`. (I've compressed the RequestLogger for readability).

```
package de.moovin.interceptor;



@Slf4j
public class RequestLoggingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postHandle( final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler,
            final ModelAndView modelAndView ) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion( final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler,
            final Exception ex ) throws Exception {
        final long startTime = ( Long ) request.getAttribute( "startTime" );
        long runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder( 350 );
        builder.append( "Path::" );
        builder.append( extractPath( request ) );
        builder.append( " - Method::" );
        builder.append( request.getMethod() );
        builder.append( " - Status::" );
        builder.append( response.getStatus() );
        builder.append( printErrorCodeIfNeeded( response ) );
        builder.append( " - User::" );
        builder.append( getClientId() );
        builder.append( " - Time::" );
        builder.append( runTime );
        builder.append( " - DONE" );
        log.info( builder.toString() );
        if ( ex != null ) {
            log.error( "Error by Exception ", ex );
        }
    }

    private String extractPath( final HttpServletRequest request ) {
        final String path = request.getRequestURI().toString();
        return path.substring( path.indexOf( "/", 1 ) );
    }

}
```

```
public class RouteMatchHelper {

    private RouteMatchHelper() {

    }

    /**
     * Avoid manual Build of Routes
     *
     * @param routes routes that should be or'd
     *
     * @return Requestmatcher that or's all routes
     */
    public static RequestMatcher orRoutes( String... routes ) {
        List<RequestMatcher> paths = Arrays.stream( routes ).map( AntPathRequestMatcher::new ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
        return new OrRequestMatcher( paths );
    }

    public static RequestMatcher combination( RequestMatcher allowedRoutes, RequestMatcher disallowedRoutes ) {
        return new AndRequestMatcher( Arrays.asList( allowedRoutes, new NegatedRequestMatcher( disallowedRoutes ) ) );
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your filter annoated by `@Component` or something alike?

Comment: @M.Deinum no, should it be? I thought it was only for autowiring and because I dont autowire, it doesnt need that. Should I add `@Component`?

Comment: No you shouldn't (and it doesn't have anything to do with autowiring but thats an aside) as that would lead to 2 instances being available. Just wanted to rule out (or confirm) that possibility. What is that `RouteMatchHelper` class doing?

Comment: The `RouteMatchHelper` only creates allowed routes. First parameter is the routes that are allowed and the second is disallowed routes (Negated). And `orRoutes` only concats the strings with AntPathMatcher and then all of them into one OrRequestMatcher

Comment: Could you add the code, feels like the issue is with the request matcher else it would apply properly.

Comment: Could you show the logging you get when you receive a 404... I suspect the error/issue lies elsewhere and is due to a redirect for which a path/page isn't available.